# Is it faster to drop a table, recreate it and reindex it than to simply delete all rows from it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's say we have a table that has 2 million rows. It has two nonclustered indices on it. Generally speaking, would it be faster to **drop** it, **recreate** it with new data and **re-apply** the indices than to **delete from** it all its rows and then do an **insert** of new data?

Note: I am trying to avoid using **trunc** as it requires sysadmin priv.

Comment: Truncate Table does not require SysAdmin. It is built in for db_owner and db_ddladmin. You need that to run the drop table also.

Comment: I was told this by one of senior DBAs. Upon investigatinng myself at the advice of the people on this site, I can now confirm that it only needs Alter table privilege. This changes things entirely and has rendered my question moot :)>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `TRUNCATE TABLE TableName` the [TRUNCATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) statement is very fast, and a better approach than dropping the table, or using `DELETE FROM`

Permissions: From the MSDN about `TRUNCATE`:

```
The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed server
role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles,
and are not transferable.

However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE statement within a module, such
as a stored procedure, and grant appropriate permissions to the module using the
EXECUTE AS clause. For more information, see Using EXECUTE AS to Create Custom
Permission Sets.
```

So you do not need `sysadmin` credentials to accomplish this.

Comment: I try to avoid using it, as it requires sysadmin priv :). I will add this to my question now.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show required credentials.  You will only need `ALTER`.  A `DROP TABLE` requires `ALTER` on the schema, or `CONTROL` on the table, or ddl_admin membership.

Answer (score 3):

James, you don't need to drop it. If you don't care about transaction logs on the delete just use Truncate table, as this won't generate transaction logs and therefore is very quick.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to avoid using trunc as it requires sysadmin priv.

That is completely inaccurate. The  [`TRUNCATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) statement requires ALTER TABLE permission:

> The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name.

So this is exactly the same permission it would be required to [`DROP INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx) and re-create, or to [`ALTER INDEX ... DISABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) the index and re-enable:

> To execute DROP INDEX, at a minimum, ALTER permission on the table or view is required. 
>   To execute ALTER INDEX, at a minimum, ALTER permission on the table or view is required.

So the faster is to TRUNCATE the table, then disable the indexes, insert the data, then enable back the indexes (which requires a rebuild of the indexes). But it would hardly worth doing such disable/enable game for a mere 2M rows. For such a small job simply truncate the table and then bulk insert the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with a similar issue and my table had around 8 million rows, with 43 columns. Dropping the indexes, Truncating the table, Performing a bulk insert, Recreating the indexes -- it still performs pretty fast, considering the amount of data, and I do perform this task during off-peak hours.

If you want to avoid using `TRUNCATE`, you may create a procedure to perform the truncate, and use a user with the right permissions. That is, if granting permissions to the job user is the reason you want to avoid using the truncate command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TruncateTableName
WITH EXECUTE AS 'SqlUserWithTruncatePermission'
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE TableName
END
GO
```

If you want to try this out, you can read more at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=SQL.90).aspx

Likewise, for other actions that require more permissions than you want, you can follow suit...